# How to get week ending next Sunday from date

Tags: r, lubridate

I know `lubridate` has a function `ceiling_date` but it provides week ending on the next Saturday from a given date. How can I change it to get the week ending next Sunday instead?

```
> ceiling_date(as.Date('2017-06-16'), 'week')
[1] "2017-06-17 20:00:00 EDT"
```

Comment: `ceiling_date(as.Date('2017-06-16'), 'week')+60*60*24`?

Comment: I think this might actually be a bug with `ceiling_date`. See https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/479 (Henrik pointed this out in another of my answers)

Comment: Adjusting it manually would be a problem when the date is a Sunday: `ceiling_date(as.Date('2017-06-18'), 'week')+60*60*24
[1] "2017-06-25 20:00:00 EDT"`

Comment: @MikeH. Was there a work-around?

Comment: How about `as.Date(paste0(year('2017-06-16'), week('2017-06-16')+1, 7), format =  "%Y%U%u")`?

Comment: Does this work `floor_date(as.Date('2017-06-16'), 'week') + weeks(1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a bug with `ceiling_date` as listed here: https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/479

One workaround might be to grab the year/week and then round to Sunday:

```
as.Date(paste0(year('2017-06-16'), week('2017-06-16') + ifelse(wday('2017-06-16')==1,0,1), 7), format =  "%Y%U%u")
#[1] "2017-06-18"
```

From `?strptime`:

- `%Y` is year with century (i.e. 2017)
- `%U` is week of year as decimal
- `%u` is day of week from 1-7 (1 is Monday)

So we need to shift our week by `1` (hence the `+1`) and then we set the day to be Sunday `7`.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified this in the question, but if the given date is a Sunday, then I was expecting a Sunday returned. `2017-06-18` stays `2017-06-18`

Comment: Ok, I edited it. Just needed to add a little conditional to check if it was Sunday already